# Datetime_select without seconds, minutes, or hours in a form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, form-for

The rails scaffolding code generates datetime_select like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :time_end %><br />
  <%= f.datetime_select :time_end, :order => [:month, :day] %>
</div>
```

However I only want to display month and day. The time helper has an option called :disable_minutes and :disable_seconds... however that doesn't work with a form_for helper.

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well first off I would use `date_select` ([api doc here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select)) and then do `:discard_year => true`.

Example:

```
date_select("article", "written_on", :discard_year => true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the :discard, e.g. :discard_year => true, :discard_hours => true

Comment: Discard_hours doesn't seem to do anything in Rails 4.  Perhaps you could give a full example?